mix terms (factor) and objects (matrix) in an R formula
Can I mix symbolic terms (eg. factor) and objects (eg. matrix) in an R formula?
For backward compatibility, I would like to specify a list of components using the R formula interface. For example:
~ component1 + component2 + component3

If all the components are (functions of) columns in a data frame, this is straightforward. However, I want to be able to specify components of different type, eg. a sparse matrix.
(Aside: In my application, each component corresponds to a covariance matrix. For example, a factor variable corresponds to a block diagonal covariance matrix. Optionally, covariance components can be constructed explicitly — as a matrix — rather than defined from a factor.)
Here is an approach using model.frame that works for factor and matrix objects:
nobs <- nrow(mtcars)

Vformula <- ~ factor(cyl) + diag(nobs)

V <- model.frame(Vformula, data = mtcars)
V <- as.list(V)

V[[1]]
#>  [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4
#> Levels: 4 6 8
V[[2]][1:6, 1:6]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    1    0    0    0    0
#> [3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0
#> [4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0
#> [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0
#> [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    1

However, model.frame throws an error if one of the components is a sparse matrix of class Matrix::ddiMatrix.
(Another aside: Often the covariance components are sparse and I can use the sparse matrix functionality provided by {Matrix}. So this is the crux of the challenge: For backward compatibility I want to specify the components via the R formula interface; for efficiency I want to specify components as sparse matrices whenever possible. These two requirements seem incompatible but I want to double check before giving up on the R formula.)
library("Matrix")

Vformula <- ~ factor(cyl) + Diagonal(nobs)

V <- model.frame(Vformula, data = mtcars)
#> Error in model.frame.default(Vformula, data = data):
#> 'data' must be a data.frame, environment, or list

The objective is to come up with a convenient way to pass these components as input to a function that can then process them differently depending on whether V[[i]] is a symbolic term or a sparse matrix.
Created on 2024-06-09 with reprex v2.1.0

The example you're showing has a typo (using data instead of mtcars in the last call).  You get a different error if that is corrected.

model.frame() is documented to return a dataframe, but a dataframe can't contain a sparse matrix.

@user2554330 Thanks I fixed the typo. I suspect that model.frame is not the way to do this. I'm starting to think that it's better to pre-process the components first (in a separate function) as it's hard to split the terms in an R formula -- which is what effectively I want to do here so that each component has its own V[[i]]. Still, I asked this question because the formula interface is familiar and simple. (Most often the components are block covariance matrices that can be efficiently represented as sparse matrices.)


a data.frame, list or environment (or object coercible by as.data.frame to a data.frame), containing the variables in formula. Neither a matrix nor an array will be accepted.

-- from https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/model.frame
You can manually create two components like:
component1 <- factor(cyl)
component2 <- Diagonal(nobs)
components <- list(component1, component2)


Thanks for the answer. However, it seems my question is not clear. I'm wondering whether I can use the R formula to get a list of what I call V[[i]]s. I don't really care about using model.frame to get that list. In fact, I already know that model.frame is not giving me what I want.

I think I need to prepare the list beforehand, without using an R formula. This is what you suggest right? The issue is that some other code isn't going to be backwards compatible.
